# How do I edit the browser used by Outlook to view emails when selecting the "View in browser" actiion?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have an issue with my Outlook 2013.

Currently when I have opened a mail and I need to inspect some HTML or CSS errors I would like to do this in the Chrome browser. But Outlook is configured to use Internet Explorer when I select the View in Browser action. Is there a way to edit it so it will view emails in the Chrome browser?

I have made sure that Chrome is selected as the standard program for all available protocols and extensions.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Found out how to edit the program. The mails were opened as `.mht` files in the browser. I switched the default program to Chrome on that extension. But apparently chrome doesn't support `.mht` files. So in the end it was useless for me.

Comment: I have the same problem it seems like it's a bug in outlook as this only applies to the 'view in browser' button above the body of an email and not to any link in the email. This suggests to me that it has nothing to do with windows 10's, 'default apps'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook is probably looking at message format as MHTML (.MHT file format).
Outlook temporarily saves the email in a temp folder, then opens that temp file.
Associating .MHT with Chrome may assist, though Chrome may not render .MHT correctly.